# delay in page load when moving from client slide page to ssr page in nextjs

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13, pageload, getserversideprops, client-side-rendering

so in my e-commerce application the homepage is ssr page(getserversideprops). and when i click on any product it open a client side product detail page. and when i click back there is certain delay in loading homepage again due to next fetched json again.there are two api calls on my getserverside props function.

so here are 2 question.

**1 - can i show any loading state for ssr page.
2 - how can i move to client side page to ssr homepage fast.**
i am using nexts 13.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can only give a general recommendation.

1. no it is not common to show a loading indicator as the whole page is rendered on the server and there is no loading state.
2. the best approach would be to keep a common SSR layout. within the layout only specific parts are interactive.

Be sure to not confuse React Server Component, Client component with Server Side Rendering and Client rendering. In Next.js also a Client component can render on the server.